# Latent space vs Embedding space | Are they same?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, autoencoder, embeddings

I am going through [variational autoencoders](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/understanding-generative-adversarial-networks-gans-cd6e4651a29) and it is mentioned that:

> continuity (two close points in the latent space should not give two
> completely different contents once decoded) and completeness (for a
> chosen distribution, a point sampled from the latent space should give
> “meaningful” content once decoded).

so is latent space merely an embedding space where two similar entities are mapped nearby in the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any embedding space is a latent space.

I'm not expert in this specific topic, but in general the term "latent space" refers to a multi-dimensional space in which elements are represented but their representation is not directly interpretable and/or observable. Typically this is in contrast to a space where dimensions have an interpretable meaning, for example in the traditional bag of words representation a dimension corresponds to a particular word.

The term "latent" applies to some variable which is not directly observable, for example the "latent variable" in a HMM is the state that the model tries to infer from the observations. It's sometimes called the "hidden variable".

Naturally a latent space is relevant only if it is meaningful with respect to the represented objects and/or the target task. This is what these sentences mean.